# Meteor call beforeSend, save request before sending on server

Tags: node.js, meteor, httprequest

i am doing a few HTTP requests on my meteor / nodejs server.

```
try {
      const result = HTTP.get(endpoint, {
        'headers': ...
        'timeout': 5000,
      });
      return { data: result.data };
    } catch (error) {
        handleError(error);
    }
```

i want to store / save my request before sending.

I use the server to send my HTTP requests. AFAIU the beforeSend is only when sending the requests from the client.

Any ideas how i can save my request before executing or can i use the beforeSend also on meteors server side?

Thx.

Comment: Where is `beforeSend` actually defined?

Comment: Not yet, i just read about it from the meteor docs: https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html